# How does Control.Enabled works?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I'd like to disable all the controls inside this Listview items. [This MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page says that Enabled is defined as Control's class property.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in eItem.Controls)
{
    ctrl.Enabled = false;
}
```

I'm getting an error "Control does not contain a definition of Enabled...". Only when I cast every control then error goes away.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in eItem.Controls)
{
    ((TextBox)ctrl).Enabled = false;
}
```

I have DropDownList, TextBox, Button, CheckBox,.. Is there a fastest and general way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you have provided misled you because it talks about *Windows Forms* control, not the *Web Forms* one. In Web Froms property `Enabled` is [defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled.aspx) in `WebControl` class, which is a subclass of `Control` and is a superclass of `TextBox`, `DropDownList` etc. So here is what you can do:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in eItem.Controls)
{
    WebControl webCtrl = ctrl as WebControl;
    if (webCtrl != null)
    {
        webCtrl.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```